# Method to automatically dial a phone number (NOT like an autodialer)

Tags: modem, phone, dial-up

I am working on a security camera system as a favour for some people I know. One aspect of the system is that, once movement is detected, a phone number is called (I am not trying to spam call anyone :-)

I need to know a way to automatically dial a phone number.

The computer running the system runs linux, and has internet access, but does NOT have physical access to a phone jack so I cannot use a local modem. Either it must have some agent on the local area network do the dialing, or use the internet in some way.

I looked into using the Skype API, but that was a massive mess and people are no longer allowed to access the developer site as it's supposedly being revamped.

The other solution I am investigating is having a network-connected microcontroller talk to a serial modem, but this seems awfully complicated for something that should be so easy.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you're looking for a solution that relies on a web service, you'll be better off asking on [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). I recommend saying which country you're in.

Answer (score 0):

Is the number a cell phone?  If so you could send it a text message using an [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway).

It looks like you may be able to so with [Google Voice](http://googlevoiceblog.blogspot.com/2009/09/receive-and-reply-to-sms-messages-by.html) as well via email.

Comment: The way the alarm monitoring company works, it must be a phone call, and unfortunately Google Voice does not operate in my country.

Answer (score 0):

1) Decide your basic need.  My guess:

- Notify one or more people by phone (because that is the device they have with them) of a security issue.

2) Brainstorm a variety of ways to accomplish that.  Thoughts:

- Modem to dial the number and then make a pattern of beeps at them.
- VOIP system to automatically play a specific audio file over the phone.
- Text messages (a few email-to-text gateways or the like out there)
- Email (for those who get email on their devices).
- other?

3) Evaluate each option you came up with and pick the one that fits the best (cost, features, etc.)

I suspect text messages might end up being the simplest approach.  Modems not for two reasons (too far from a jack, + the message you can send is imprecise at best.)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely this can be done with skype.  And quite easily:

On Linux, the CLI for Skype is as follows:

`"skype --callto echo123"`

Java code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.skype;

import java.io.*;

public class SkypeEchoTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String s = null;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("skype --callto echo123");
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24483653/262852